# Setting duration of a freeswitch call

Tags: freeswitch

I'm a bit new on freeswitch but I'd like to call a number, play a sound and hang up after a certain amount of time. It could be that the call lasts longer or shorter then the sound file.

I was hoping to do it with Javascript and I got as far as

```
session.waitForAnswer(10000);


if (session.ready()) {
    session.streamFile('/path-to-sound.wav');
    session.hangup();
}
```

Is there a way I can set an auto hangup time through javascript becuase I can keep the call open by looping a sound file of silence.

I'm using javascript because I want to keep the sound file and duration as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with "sched_api" call, you can schedule an execution of "hangup" call. Is that what you want?

Comment: Maybe but I'm struggling to see how I'd implement it

Comment: I've done it 


var calllength = "3";
session.execute("sched_hangup","+"+calllength+" alloted_timeout");
    if (session.ready()) {
      session.streamFile('/root/piano2.wav');
}

Answer (score 1):

You have an example of inplementation below.

```
  <action application="set" data="execute_on_answer=sched_hangup+60alloted_timeout" /> 
  <action application="bridge" data="sofia/external/1234567@10.10.10.10"/>
```

From:

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_sched_hangup